# Can't access Django admin page it gives an error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Can't access Django admin page it gives an error as below

[image: Admin Page Error]

in addition I have created a super user as 'admin' with a password and with an email.

somebody please help, since I'm unable to fix the error by myself.
my urls.py url patterns goes as below:

```
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), url(r'^', include('personal.urls')), url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')), ]
```

and the setting.py as below

[image: Settings area]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re-migrate your database will fix this error

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This problem is caused by version changing

Comment: Your point saved me from pulling my hair